# jQuery click() event

Tags: jquery, click

What is wrong in this piece of html code with some jquery functions?
I don't understand why is not working jquery functions!
Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>  
    <style> 
      p { color:red; margin:5px; cursor:pointer; } 
      p.hilite { background:yellow; } 
     </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("p").click(function () {
            $(this).slideUp();
            return false;
        });

        $("p").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("hilite");
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hilite");
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Click</h2>

    <p>First Paragraph</p> 
    <p>Second Paragraph</p> 
    <p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me either ! What is not working? the event is not trigger? trigger twice ?

Comment: No, the code is not right. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to :

```
<html>
<head>  
<style> 
  p { color:red; margin:5px; cursor:pointer; } 
  p.hilite { background:yellow; } 
 </style> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ // that is trigger when the document is loaded
       $("p").click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp();
        return false;
       });

       $("p").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hilite");
       }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hilite");
       });
    });

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Click</h2>

<p>First Paragraph</p> 
<p>Second Paragraph</p> 
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your bindings are executed before the DOM is ready, as you didn't wrap them in the `$(function() {})` so the paragraphs do not exist when the bindings are performed.

EDIT

Sample code:

```
$(function() {
        $("p").click(function () {
            $(this).slideUp();
            return false;
        });

        $("p").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("hilite");
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hilite");
        }); 
});
```

Comment: As I suggested. Wrap your code in the $(function() { //your code here })

Answer (score 0):

**@[david-laberge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732497/david-laberge)**,
 There is no need to put `click()` event inside the `document.ready()` if it is not an event that have to be executed only after document has been ready.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `<script>....</script>` at the end of your body tag and put an `alert()` inside the click event to know.It will work..